# updating values in table to remove specific word

Tags: sql-server, trim

[image]

Some of my data has **- Automated** two or more times. I need to replace the text so it only appears once

I first tried to get the value to display by using this failed query

```
SELECT TRIM('- Automated') As TrimmedString FROM 
    (SELECT Comments FROM TableName WHERE Comments LIKE '%- Automated')
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_trim.asp

Answer (score 1):

(In general, all these string-manipulation functions only operate *on their arguments*; if a column name is not one of the arguments, you are not manipulating the column!)

`TRIM()` is for trimming given characters *in whatever order and quantity they may occur*; if you want to trim given characters *only if they occur as particular strings*, `TRIM()` is the wrong tool.

There is no `STRIP()` function in the list of SQL Server Functions at the link you provided, but `REPLACE()` is there, and **replacing *X* with an empty string** is same as stripping *X*; so, try

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(Comments , '- Automated' , '') AS TrimmedString
FROM TableName
WHERE Comments LIKE '%- Automated'
```

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction:

With the question as asked, there are two possibilities (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc42a3d6751d6d64586c31322b338dfe)):

Create your table:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
  x INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  y VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it with some test data:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
(1, 'test'),
(2, ' - test - test'),
(3, 'test'),
(4, ' - test - test'),
(5, 'test'),
(6, 'test - test'),
(7, ' - test test'),
(8, ' xxxx - test -test'),
(9, 'other stuff');
```

### Shotgun approach:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('test', y, 1) = 0 THEN y
    ELSE 'test'
  END AS new_y
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
new_y
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
other stuff
```

What this does is

- simply test (i.e. `CASE`) if the string contains your target word (in this case, I've used `test`)
- if not - i.e. [`CHARINDEX()`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc42a3d6751d6d64586c31322b338dfe) = 0, then just output the string which may contain anything **but** the word `test` -- `**OR**`
- if it does **not** = 0 (i.e. `test` is there), then just output the word `test` - stripping anything else which may be there - hyphens, other words &c. before or after the first occurrence of the test word!

### More subtle approach:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('test', y, 1) = 0 THEN y
    ELSE SUBSTRING(y, 1, CHARINDEX('test', y, 1) + 3) -- 3 + 1 = length of test!
  END AS new_y
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
new_y
test
 - test 
test
 - test 
test
test 
 - test 
 xxxx - test 
other stuff
```

So, anything in front of the first occurrence of the word `test` will be kept using the [`SUBSTRING()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp) function and adding the length of `test` (i.e. 4) to the first occurrence, and truncating the string at the end of the first occurrence of `test` and no further.

### The update

Apart from realising that there was a  small flaw in my initial logic - it should be 3 instead of 4 in the SQL - 3 + 1 = the length of `test` - the first character is included anyway, I realised that I hadn't done the `UPDATE` - it can be done as follows:

```
UPDATE
    t
SET
    t.y = tab.new_y
FROM
    test AS t
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    x,
    CASE
      WHEN CHARINDEX('test', y, 1) = 0 THEN y
      ELSE SUBSTRING(y, 1, CHARINDEX('test', y, 1) + 3) -- 3 + 1 = length of test!
    END AS new_y
  FROM test
) AS tab
ON t.x = tab.x;
```

The fiddle shows: `9 rows affected`.

Then, to check: `SELECT * FROM test` - result:

```
x   y
1   test
2    - test
3   test
4    - test
5   test
6   test
7    - test
8    xxxx - test
9   other stuff
```

i.e. our stripped table. The SQL Server `UPDATE` proved tricky - it's not my go-to server - I got help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match). Revised fiddle is at the [link above](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc42a3d6751d6d64586c31322b338dfe).